# Translation of 'time' to Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Google gives the word 'Tempus' and 'Aevum' but they seem like they mean moment and age. Is there a more appropriate translation for the word 'Time,' definition of:

**"*the indefinite continued progress of existence and events in the past, present, and future regarded as a whole.*"**

**"*a nonspatial continuum that is measured in terms of events which succeed one another from past through present to future.*"**

Thank you for your help

Comment: [This thread](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/how-to-say-time-the-devourer?rq=1) might be related.

Answer (score 1):

Traupman gives *tempus* for time and *aetas* for age, and *tempus* means more than just a point, it also means a season or a period and quite a few other things: consult your dictionary. *Tempus* is, as Manuel said, probably the word you want. Although you do have other options as well, including *spatium*, which can refer to time as well as space, and *intervallum*, which can also refer to more than just space.